Triggering onReceive() after reboot
I am creating an app, and I would like to show a notification to the user after booting or rebooting, to inform the user that the app is available if interested.
From what I understood, the following code should work
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "BootReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "BootReceiver triggered");
    }
}

The log unfortunately does not show up. If I understand correctly, everytime an action is performed (like: ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED or ACTION_USER_PRESENT), the onReceive() method should be triggered right? Or am I wrong?
For example, I know that these actions are restricted in recent androids, but I understood somehow that still onReceive() should work, and what may not work is the following code:
if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction()) {}

Also, I understood that these actions are restricted for background activities, so: is pushing a notification permitted? If yes, how?

edit: here I report my manifest declaration
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>


"Or am I wrong?" -- simply having a class is insufficient. You need to register the receiver somehow, such as via the manifest.

@CommonsWare, thank you for your help. I edited the question and reported the manifest declaration. From what I understood, this should work. But somehow the onReceive() method is not appearing in my logs (it appears for other apps).

Just declaring the broadcasts in the Manifest of the app is not enough. You also need to register and unregister a receiver in the context environment where the broadcast will be processed.
You already have the declaration of the broadcast included in your Manifest. That's good.
You now only have to start and stop the receiver. I would recommend to do that in the onResume() and onPause() lifecycle methods as shown below:
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    requireActivity().registerReceiver(updateReceiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED)
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()

    requireActivity().unregisterReceiver(updateReceiver)
}

With this you receive the broadcast. You can then react on it as needed.

You're on the right track, but there are a few key points to address to ensure that the BootReceiver works correctly before you push a notification after the device has booted/rebooted.

Permissions in the Manifest (which you already did).
The android:exported="true" attribute allows the receiver to be invoked by other apps (in this case, the system).
To ensure that your BootReceiver is triggered:
a. The app should be installed in the internal storage (not on the SD card).
b. The app must be launched at least once before the BootReceiver can receive broadcasts.

